# Keep error count and get top ten with associated word?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a few hundred words in arrays in a plist, somewhat like below:

```
PLIST:
Array 1:
  - words here
  -
  -
  -

Array 2:
  -
  -
  -
  -
  -

etc...
```

Now I need to have a number associated with every word which increments so that I can then fetch the top 10 most failed words (top ten with highest count). This what I can't get my head around, how to keep a number associated with a word and then get the top ten most incorrect words.

I'd like to figure out a better method; I have my list of words, perhaps a number is needed, but I need to keep a record of the most common errors (I have a method which is called when an error is made, I just need to know how to store the error so I can retrieve the ten most incorrect words later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the words in dictionaries. The words will be the keys, and the objects (values) the number of times an error was made for that word. Then you can enumerate all the words and access the number of times a word was wrong by access the dictionary's value for that word.